# Windows10: What is "Service CPU Usage"?

Tags: windows-10, resource-monitor

On the CPU tab of the Resource Monitor of Windows 10 64 bit, it shows the "CPU - Total" graph and 1 graph for each CPU, but then it also shows a graph for "Service CPU Usage".

What is "Service CPU Usage"?

[image]

Comment: I tried "windows10 what is service CPU usage" (with and without quotes around the embedded phrase) and got a whole bunch of issues with high CPU usage not related to service CPU usage. Leaving out Windows 10 does in fact show the answer in the first result.

Comment: I've also tried googling what is service cpu usage and now the top link is this question, so thank you @simpleuser!

Comment: I did try googling What is "Service CPU Usage"? It brought me here

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input @Ale..chenski

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the same in Windows 8.1

The subtotal of CPU usage for all the svchost.exe's or services that are part of Windows Services.  Each generation of Windows has compartmentalized tasks to restrict permissions to "NetworK" "System" "Dcom" etc which are like functions within Windows with group restrictions to improve security.

As a result. the number of Windows services have increased at least 50% or so each generation from XP to X so there are several hundred services grouped by Process host "svchost"

My services do not have Windows Search enabled which with Windows Update can make your PC sluggish if limited in power and RAM.

I prefer my PC lean and fast rather than bloated security apps.
e.g. below  CPU is usually 2% on i5-quad 8GB laptop and services =0%
[image]

The only security I need is a dog who barks at the door.(Molly) same as on my PC (Scotty from Winpatrol)  All other features like Windows Defender have been disabled for years. I've have been following this practice for about 10 yrs with good results.  ( your mileage may vary)